# Kendo grid on edit number display `,` seperator

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create a simple demo here. When edit at `amount` field I want to display `,` separator ? Currently it only display the `,` when not in edit mode. Any idea how to achieve this?

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/EwomoYif)

```js
var data = [{ "name": 'Venue A', "amount": 10000.50}, 
{"name": 'Venue B', "amount": 250000.00}, 
{"name": 'Venue C', "amount": 1500000.43 }];

$(document).ready(function () {
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
          name: { type: "string"  },
          amount: { type: "amount"  }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource, 
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
    columns: [
    { field:"name" , title: "Name"},
    { field: "amount", title: "Amount", format: "{0:n}" }],
    editable: true
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model/methods/define) you only have the following types allowed:

```
The available dataType options are:
"string"
"number"
"boolean"
"date"
"object"
(Default) "default"
```

I suggest you to use "number" in this case, as it will work for sorting and filtering.

You can check that Kendo doesn't understand the "amount" type by writing some incorrect text in the editor and see it stays as it was.

You can create your own editor as shown in [this dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/ofaZafIn):

```
 { field: "amount", title: "Amount", format: "{0:c}",
   editor: function(container, options) {
       const input = $(`<input name="${options.field}">`).appendTo(container);
       input.kendoNumericTextBox({
           format: "c"
       });
    }
  }
```

However, if you test Kendo NumericTextBox [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/format), you'll see it doesn't display the section separators when editing.

You could do a custom text editor and handle all the events - that's a pure JavaScript question.